# Google sheet, lookup a value to get whole column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Here is my problem:

I have a table starting in A1 with D

```
D C B A
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

I want a function that returns me the column of data of whatever letter give it.

ie input:`=function("C")`

output:

```
2
6
```

input: `=function("A")`

output:

```
4
8
```

I can't just `query` because the column is changing.

`Hlookup`? but how do you get the whole column as a return?

Comment: say if i want column with heading `C` statement would be `=query(A1:D3,"select B where B='C')` now I want column with heading `A`, `=query(A1:D3,"select D where D='A')`. The letter behind `select` needs some type of matching with column letters. I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: yeah you're right, so how do I make it dynamic?

Comment: I'm pasting this formula into many spreadsheets. I wouldn't waste my time trying to get a "cute" formula for 10 characters.

Comment: ha... ok... anybody else?

Comment: @pnuts, the OP would like to retrieve the column that has a certain string in the header, whether it is "C", "Foo" or "Strawberries".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly:

`=FILTER(A2:D3,A1:D1=A5)`

Comment: Thanks Adam. I find your answers are always correct and the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

not pretty but it works.

`=indirect(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(hlookup(A5,A1:D3,2,false)),4),"1","")&"2:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(hlookup(A5,A1:D3,2,false)),4),"1","")&"3")`

`A5` being the place where you enter the letter

Answer (score 0):

With a trigger cell in A5 and in say A6:

`="select "&A5`

```
=query($A$1:$D$3,$A$6,0)
```

might suit.

This might be placed almost anywhere and produce the same results, with such results controlled by the value (letter) chosen in `A5`. Perhaps parameterised rather than dynamic.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. If I put in "C" I get 3 7, not 2 6 like I want because "C" is actually asking for column B. So there needs to be some kind of a lookup function.

Comment: This is why in the example I on purpose flipped the letter heading to D C B A.